# SQL Server 2005: Getting error when setting auto increment on one of two primary keys

Tags: sql-server-2005, composite-primary-key

I am getting an error 
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

The table has two primary key, one is set to auto-increment, one is set with value i passed into.

Is this possible in SQL Server 2005? or am i missing something?

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: how are you able to make two primary keys? you can only have one pk.

Comment: well.. we do have composite-primary-keys. eventhough i'm not sure the maximum number of primary keys.
You just press ctrl-click on the columns you want to set as primary key, right-click, and "Set Primary key".

:) hope this is what u looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert a value into an identity column
You can do this by

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
INSERT INTO TableName() VALUES ()
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question. 
Eventhough my solution is to stop trying to insert value into the auto-incrementing column.

Thanks nonnb!!~~